# Optimizing canvas animation (sine curve)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

how can I optimize this code to render sine wave without little blurring that happens when canvas is re-drawen

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("sinewave");
var points = {};
var counter = 0;
var intensity = 0;

function f(x, intensity) {
    return intensity * Math.sin(0.25 * x) + 100;
}

if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    var x = 0,
        y = f(0,0);
    var timeout = setInterval(function() {
        if(counter < 400) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            x += 1;
            y = f(x, intensity);
            points[x] = y;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();
            if (x > 1000) {
                clearInterval(timeout);
            }
        } else {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
            ctx.beginPath();
            points[x] = y;
            x += 1;
            y = f(x, intensity);
            for(var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
                ctx.lineTo(i, points[i + counter - 400]);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        counter++;

    }, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some thoughts:**

1. Since x==0 & intensity==0 the first 400 plots form a straight line(?).
2. Your setInterval time is too short (5ms).  The screen refreshes only about every 17ms so you are accumulating interval calls that the browser will futilely try to fill. (You're getting clogged up!).
3. Use the new(ish) requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval because requestAnimationFrame is better integrated with the display hardware.

Here's example refactored code and Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MZ7Ap/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: black; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    var points = {};
    var counter = 0;
    var intensity = 2;
    var x = 0;
    var y = fz(0,0);

    animate();

    function fz(x, intensity) {
        return intensity * Math.sin(0.25 * x) + 100;
    }

    function animate(time){

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        draw(counter);

        counter++;

    }

    function draw(counter){
        if(counter < 400) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            x += 1;
            y = fz(x, intensity);
            points[x] = y;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();
            if (x > 1000) {
                clearInterval(timeout);
            }
        } else {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
            ctx.beginPath();
            points[x] = y;
            x += 1;
            y = fz(x, intensity);
            for(var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
                ctx.lineTo(i, points[i + counter - 400]);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=900 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AMAZING!
Thanks, would be also kind to suggest how to limit the height of the function through the equation?
So that even with 100000 intensity it wont be higher than canvas height

Comment: You're welcome!  The max/min sine values are 1.00 and -1.00.  So working backwards from your f(): minIntensity=100 and maxIntensity=canvas.height-100.  If you want to use values outside these min/max you will have to scale the intensity value (which will also skew your wave since your x values are advancing 1 pixel per calculation.